# SSRS report merge cells vertically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to merge cells based on same data.
so i can only display a single instance for 2,3,4 day events
right now every event is separate.
[SSRS Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7OPl.png)

if not possible recommend me another tool to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can merge cells (click an both cells, right click and merge) but not in your case, because every one of your column has another weekday which should be the same field value `=Fields!Weekday.Value`. And in the detail section you also have just a field value `=Fields!YourValue.Value`. So if you would merge two cells with a different weekday name, its impossible for SSRS to match the `Fields!YourValue.Value` with the `Fields!Weekday.Value`.

Comment: There were many limitations for the SSRS to build a calander like view to many conditions for multiple group by. I moved that project to Gridview instead of SSRS report. Thanks